# TImage does not resize

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a `TImage` on a resizable Form, and I want it to resize when I resize the Form.

What I tried:

- enabling all `Anchors` options
- putting the `TImage` on a `TPanel`, and then setting both Panel and Image alignments to `alClient`
- Assigning new `Width` and `Height` in the Form's `OnResize` event

None of these does the job.

This is the default Form size. The `TImage` gets redrawn whenever any of the parameters on the left change, or if the image is zoomed in/out (using the mouse scroll wheel). On each redraw, the pattern repeats until it fills the full `TImage`.

[image]

And this is the Form after resizing. Notice that the image size remains unchanged.

[image]

Enabling the `Stretch` property does work, but it also scales the image's content, which I don't want.

How can I fix this?

I'm on Delphi 10.3

Comment: All these methods are working. What do you mean `None if these does the job.` ? What do you expect to see?

Comment: @MBo -- I agree that these methods should work, but if they did (for me) I wouldn't post the question, would I? I've added screenshots to illustrate what happens (or rather, doesn't happen)

Comment: I set anchors for Image. When I load large picture, then resize form, image extends, redrawing picture. When I load small picture,  then resize form, I don't see visually that image changes because picture remains in the left top corner, and the rest of image is transparent. But image dimensions do change.

Comment: Which version of Delphi do you use?

Comment: 10.2.3 and XE3.   Screenshot shows "threads" - is this important here?

Comment: No no, threads here means strands or fibers in the tartan :-). But thanks for paying attention.

Comment: So your background picture has size bigger than image itself? Or you draw it at image canvas "by hands"? Timage has some peculiarities with picture redrawing, so it is worth to describe details

Comment: The pattern repeats until it fills the complete TImage. Works flawlessly with zooming in/out, which causes redraws, as does changing any of the parameters on the left.

Comment: `The pattern repeats until it fills the complete TImage`  and who and when calls redrawing? Consider making minimal  reproducible example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rereading your description, I see the problem.

When image dimensions change, inner picture doesn't change its size, if stretching is off. You have to modify inner bitmap size by hands:

```
Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Width := Image2.Width;
Image2.Picture.Bitmap.Height := Image2.Height;
//now diagonal is drawn properly
Image2.Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
Image2.Canvas.LineTo(Image2.Width, Image2.Height);
```

Comment: That's it exactly! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: And it explains why, when debugging, the TImage did indeed changes size, though without visible effect.

Comment: @stevenvh Just an FYI, for something like this, I probably would have used a `TPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`

Comment: TImage is intended to show static pictures with possibility to draw on its canvas. Suitable when you don't need instant fast update, convenient because you don't need to care about redrawing (stores a picture inside). For quick redrawing (animation, large pic scrolling etc) - yes, TPaintbox would be better.